# -ms-overflow-style on iframes

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have a website with an iframe as the main content area.  When I apply the below css it behaves as expected and removes scrollbars from the page.

```
html{
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

But I want the iframe itself to allow scrollbars so I override the above with a more specific rule using the below.

```
iframe{
    -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
}
```

When inspecting the element with a developer's tool you can clearly see the style is in place but it is not doing as it should and the scrollbars are still absent.  Is this a bug or am I missing something?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibE7e.png)

From the image, I want the page scrollbars removed but the iframe scrollbars still intact.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the setting but it's unlikely to work with iframes for multiple reasons. Most likely, you should set it on the html element of the document included by the iframe.

Comment: @Alohci This is a Microsoft style to handle the disappearing scrollbars in IE11 and Edge.  But the setting itself works for iframes.  I can control the scrollbar style of the iframes with it but cannot override the hierarchy.

Comment: This has nothing to do with CSS specificity. Specificity as defined by CSS refers to the concept of multiple selectors matching the same element, but in your example you're targeting two different elements altogether.

Comment: @BoltClock Edited misleading title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Alohci had mentioned, I did need to set this inside of the document called by the iframe rather than in the parent.

Parent / Master Page:

```
html,
body {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

Child / Document called by iframe:

```
body {
  -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the vertical scrollbars are caused by the horizontal one because your page is too wide.

Try searching what makes your page larger than needed, then the window scrollbars should disappear.

Answer (score -3):

```
html, body {
    position:relative;
    height:100%
}
İframe {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what this answer is trying to convey.